# How do I use the SSIS configuration manager? i.e. to easily set Dev or Test or Prod configurations to a process?

Tags: ssis, configuration

Other integration tools allow setup of connections for various level of deployment. i.e. Dev, Test, Prod and it is just a matter of switching (choosing) dev or test or prod and the connections are all as per those settings ..  e.g. Talend integration tool has context variables and context environments ..

[image]

The Talend context environment can be set post deployment even in TAC.

Assume SSIS and SSMS have same capabilities as this. (I just need to learn how to use).

Any pointers to doco/courses/youtube where I can learn about using this in SSIS ?

I can see the SSIS "Solution Configurations" drop down offering me Dev, Test, Prod ... 
I can see the "Configuration Manager..." option and have a whole lot of content in this dialog .. 
But I'm not sure how this is used/setup here in SSIS ?

[image]

I have tried to create a Prod "New Project Configuration" for the current project but I get message "This configuration could not be created because a solution configuration of the same name already exists."
I will check to see if any MS doco on this.

[image]

Comment: I spotted this article which indicates that SSMS is used for setting up "Environments" and variables per environment.   https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2013/9/15/getting-started-with-parameters-variables-configurations-in.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure environment variable to switch between test/dev/prod environment. Please see this Link:

- [Setup Environment Variables in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4810/setup-environment-variables-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Comment: Thanks ! I've had a read of this article .. I will have a try at putting into practice also.